# How to use frame-src and child-src in Firefox and other browsers?

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

The [MDN page on Content Security Policy directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) states the frame-src is deprecated and child-src should be used. However, Firefox 37 gives the following error message when I attempt to use child-src

```
Content Security Policy: Couldn't process unknown directive 'child-src' <unknown>
```

This apparent lack of support isn't documented (as far as I could tell) which is frustrating. Is there any place browser support is documented?

Currently I'm using frame-src in addition to child-src, which appears to work. However I'm now wondering if there is any potential for conflict between the two. Presumably frame-src will be ignored by browsers that support child-src? Is that guaranteed?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Update:** Jan 2017:

Stop using `child-src` and begin using `frame-src` again.

In an effort to create even more confusion, CSP Level 3 has undeprecated `frame-src` and actually re-appointed it as the preferred way to achieve this. While `child-src` is still supported `frame-src` is once again preferred.

---

**Old post**

`frame-src` **is** deprecated, but it was only recently made so in CSP Level 2 and not all browsers are up to the latest version of the spec.

The best approach at the moment for maximum browser compatibility is to include both `child-src` and `frame-src` with identical values. Browsers that only support the original CSP specification will use `frame-src` while newer ones will use `child-src`.

That developer console warning is of no consequence and merely informational. I would suggest you ignore it for now, because a year from now you may very well see one saying that `frame-src` is deprecated.

At this time, I ensure both are used when this is needed and intend to stop providing `frame-src` in January of 2017.

CSP Level 2 support:

- Firefox - [Pending](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=968586)
- Chrome - 40+
- Opera - 27+
- Microsoft Edge - [Pending](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/contentsecuritypolicylevel2/)
- Safari - 10+

Comment: See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1288896 - in practice you may need both `frame-src` and `child-src` and the fact that Firefox emits that warning is just a bug.

Comment: Rabbit hole alert - I started getting these warnings in my application, however, the warnings don't give context to what spawned them. Through trial and error, in my application it was a 3rd-party script from intercom.io.