# Content Security Policy - child-src

Tags: apache, content-security-policy

I have the following issue:

In my `oxid`shop I get the following error, when I try to save at a certain point:

> Couldn't process unknown directive 'child-src'.

I tried it on a different server and everything works fine. I just fetched the headers (on the failing server) to have a look at the CSP and this is the output:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.nrw.de *.google.com *.twimg.com;    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.nrw.de *.twitter.com;    font-src 'self' *.example.org;    img-src data: *.example.org;    child-src *.example.org *.nrw.de *.facebook.com *.facebook.de *.twitter.com *.google.com;    frame-src *.example.org *.nrw.de *.facebook.com *.facebook.de *.twitter.com *.google.com;    object-src 'none';    media-src *.example.org;

content-security-policy: default-src 'self';    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.nrw.de *.google.com *.twimg.com;    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.example.org *.twitter.com;    font-src *;    img-src data: *.example.org;    child-src *.example.org *.nrw.de *.facebook.com *.facebook.de *.twitter.com *.google.com;    frame-src *.example.org *.nrw.de *.facebook.com *.facebook.de *.twitter.com *.google.com;    object-src 'none';    media-src *.example.org;
```

Any ideas? Need more info?

Thanks in advance

Comment: child-src is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/child-src)

Comment: use frame-src instead [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023608/how-to-use-frame-src-and-child-src-in-firefox-and-other-browsers)

Comment: Mozilla says child-src is deprecated and you should use frame-src instead (just as @user10089632 said)... but https://content-security-policy.com says the exact opposite! Personally, I'll trust what the W3C says: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-src (looks like Mozilla is wrong...)

Answer (score 0):

"child-src" is a new directive introduced in version 2 of Content-Security-Policy.  See the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/

Most browsers now support v1, but not all support v2.  See this page for compatibility details
http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2

Browsers should just ignore any directives they don't support

You say you tried a different server and got different results.  Were you using the same browser, or a different one?  It's likely to be the browser that makes a difference.

Comment: Tested in on the same browser.