# Content Security Policy: Directive 'frame-src' has been deprecated. Please use directive 'child-src' instead

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

I am working in a codeigniter framework and suddenly the site i am working on has stopped working properly in firefox and stating the following error.

Content Security Policy: Directive 'frame-src' has been deprecated. Please use directive 'child-src' instead.

I have not written frame-src or anything anywhere in the code yet it is giving me that error. any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Its working perfectly well in Chrome...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023608/how-to-use-frame-src-and-child-src-in-firefox-and-other-browsers

Comment: Please, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/child-src)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use frame-src and child-src in Firefox and other browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023608/how-to-use-frame-src-and-child-src-in-firefox-and-other-browsers)

Answer (score 2):

The "content-security-policy"  is not in your code (usually) but it is a [HTTP header field.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)
You just need to change the header field ("content-security-policy") that your server sends for each request.

Remove the header if you do not need it (not recommended) or try to replace the string "frame-src" with "child-src".

To check if the changes work, look in the [developer tools of Chrome](https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/).

Comment: See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1288896 - in practice you may need both `frame-src` and `child-src` and the fact that Firefox emits that warning is just a bug.