# How to fix the frame-src - child-src error from firefox in angular 2

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

> Content Security Policy: Directive 'frame-src' has been deprecated.
>   Please use directive 'child-src' instead.

We found this error on firefox recently and couldn't manage to find an appropriate answer for this...

What is the best solution for Angular 2 on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular. FF is merely advising you of an issue with your Contest Security Poiicy (which you can most likely find in a `meta` tag in `index.html`). Just read it and do what it says. However, please note that in the [CSP Level 3 Draft](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/), `frame-src` has been un-deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, I found this information, that the frame-src has been  undeprecated... problems is, should we insert this on our index? Because this seems to be a firefox only problem...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023608/how-to-use-frame-src-and-child-src-in-firefox-and-other-browsers, which recommends ignoring the warning.