# Loading data from different origin in IFrame is not working in MS-Edge

Tags: java, iframe, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I am trying to load data from different origin in IFrame but MS-edge is giving error:

> CSP14309: Unknown directive 'child-src' in Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.
>
> CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'frame-src http://example2.com' in Content-Security-Policy: ms-appx-web:///assets/errorpages/dnserror.html. Resource will be blocked.

I am adding "http://example2.com" in both 'child-src' and 'default-src'.

It is working properly in Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use frame-src and child-src in Firefox and other browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023608/how-to-use-frame-src-and-child-src-in-firefox-and-other-browsers)

Comment: What's your Edge browser version? From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/child-src), we can see the 'child-src' support Edge 15 Version

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Edge version is Edgehtml14  . I have tried in Edgehtml13 & Edgehtml15 too.

Comment: On the EdgeHtml 15+, do you meet the same error? Try to use [frame-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src), or upgrade the Edge browser to the latest version.

Comment: Was Working on jboss8 so it was not working and after upgrading to jboss11 its working properly